# Gradle Single JAR Dependency from AWS S3 with IAM Policy

Tags: gradle, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a gradle build file which requires a certain jar file as a dependency.

The jar file resides on AWS in an S3 bucket.

The gradle build file is executed on Jenkins, and the Jenkins box has an IAM policy already to allow it to upload and download from S3 (I don't control the policy so I can't provide much more info on that).

In my gradle build file I specify the S3 bucket as a repository like so:

```
maven {
    url "s3://myBucket/myPath"
    credentials(AwsCredentials) {
        accessKey = awsCredentials.AWSAccessKeyId
        secretKey = awsCredentials.AWSSecretKey
    }
}
```

Currently I supply AWS credentials which are fetched as so:

```
def fetchAwsCredentials = {
    try {
        return new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        println("unable to get credentials: " + e.getMessage())
    }
}
AWSCredentials awsCredentials = fetchAwsCredentials().getCredentials()
```

And finally I attempt to get the required JAR file in the dependencies section as so:

```
testCompile files('myJarFile.jar')
```

When running the Jenkins job that executes the gradle build, it retrieves AWS credentials from the Jenkins instance fine (as no Exception is caught) but it simply does not pick up the JAR file.
I have tried adding a non-existant JAR file as a dependency and I get no error from the build that it could not be found.

My main question is, how do I specify an IAM policy rather than an access key and secret key? I have checked gradle documentation and cannot see anything about supporting IAM authentication, other than the following error if I don't specify any credentials at all:

> S3 resource should either specify AwsIamAutentication or provide some AwsCredentials

[sic]

I'm also interested why using the instance credentials does not work, and why I don't get an error during the build stating it could not find the dependency - the error I get is that my tests fail due to the missing JAR file dependency.

Any info appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So not long after posting, I found the answer in the Gradle documentation (in plainer view than I care to admit..)

I believe that specifying the S3 bucket as a repository, but then attempting to get the JAR file dependency as a file (*testCompile files*) is not possible.

Since the S3 bucket is defined as a repository, it needs the full GAV description.

Therefore I amended my dependency to *testCompile "someGroup:someArtifact:someVersion@jar"* which now picks up the dependency.

My tests still aren't working, but I think that's another issue. I can see the JAR file listed as a dependency now when I print them all to the console.

I would still be interested if anyone thinks I am incorrect and that it is possible to specify a single JAR file rather than artifact, from an S3 bucket, as otherwise I need to turn the JAR file into an artifact which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Could you share the Gradle documentation link?

Comment: Sorry, this was so long ago I can't remember where I saw the relevant comment, plus it was most likely gradle 4 or earlier so may not be relevant to gradle 5 now.

Comment: no problem...I actually found the relevant documentation here:  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/repository_types.html#sub:supported_transport_protocols.  I believe example 18 in that section addresses your question.